# Super expression must either be null or a function, not number. Upgrading Expo SDK 26

Tags: react-native, expo

im having issues upgrading a React Native App from Expo sdk 21 to Expo sdk 26.

I have followed this steps:

1) In app.json, change sdkVersion to "26.0.0"
2) In package.json, change these dependencies:

- react-native to "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz"
- expo to "^26.0.0"
- react to ("16.3.0-alpha.1" — this exact version)
- react-navigation to "1.5.8"

Previously, i was using:

- expo ^21.0.2
- react-navigation ^1.0.0-beta.21"
- react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
- react-native": "^0.48.4"

Now im getting this error, i dont know where start to search or debug.. any ideas?

[image: app]

This are the full dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "expo": "^21.0.2",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "native-base": "^2.3.2",
    "npm": "^5.4.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-directed-scrollview": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-inputs": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-lazyload-components": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.4",
    "react-native-material-design-searchbar": "^1.1.7",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.10.2",
    "react-native-rest-client": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-snackbar-component": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "react-navigation-redux-debouncer": "^0.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Any ideas of how i can get the line, library or something that is making this conflict?

Kind regards

Comment: Try going through each of Expo's upgrade posts from v21 to v26. There are other dependencies that have been updated in-between. Fix that first and see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks. But the only other libraries are -jest-expo and sentry-expo, right?

Comment: Maybe? I'd have to go look. If those are the only other ones, then edit your question to make it clear that you've done all the steps in between. We aren't mind readers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error was kind of dificult to debug, but the problem was a circular dependency in my code.

The `"Super expression must either be null or a function.."` message is a ES6 babel way to tell you that you have errors in your imports/ circular dependencies.

So after fixing that theres a lot of work to do, as @Michael Cheng saids, a lot of libraries did breaking changes between SDK21 and SDK26.